# Excel calculate product stock

Tags: excel

I have an Excel book with following sheets,

[Sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aqyc.png),[Purchase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKriv.png),[Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JTET.png),[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2ROn.png)

In report I am trying to calculate profit between two dates base on purchase sales and stock. Using sum if am able to get total sales and total purchases. But I am lost in finding opening and closing stock. Can any one help me.

> Opening Stock Units  = (Product opening stock + Purchase units before
>   From Date – Sales units before From Date)
>
> Opening Stock Amount = Opening Stock Units  * Product Cost
>
> Closing Stock Units= (Opening Stock Units + Purchase Units between
>   dates) – Sales Units between dates
>
> Closing Stock Amount =  Closing Stock Units * Product Cost

Comment: are you not missing a date column in the worksheet product?

Comment: No, product sheet contains all products with opening and closing stock for all time

Comment: In your Report Sheet, what would be the right answer in  opening and closing stock?

Comment: updating result i am expecting in question

Answer (score 0):

Opening stock purchase value (using product name--not sure if you want to use "sn"):

`=SUMPRODUCT((SUMIFS(Purchase[Units],Purchase[Date],"<"&C1,Purchase[Product],Product[Product])-SUMIFS(Sales[Units],Sales[Date],"<"&C1,Sales[Product],Product[Product])),Product[Cost])`

Closing stock purchase value:

`=SUMPRODUCT((SUMIFS(Purchase[Units],Purchase[Date],"<="&C2,Purchase[Product],Product[Product])-SUMIFS(Sales[Units],Sales[Date],"<="&C2,Sales[Product],Product[Product])),Product[Cost])`

Comment: Above one will get me units of stock, But I want to calculate amount, which is multiplication of cost price with each products units of stock.

Comment: Again, calculating the purchase value of your inventory may not be trivial depending on how you're tracking it. Is it possible to have multiple purchases with the same sn? (My guess is yes. Which means if those purchases have varying unit costs, you'll have to keep track of the cost of each unit sold, which will vary.)

Comment: cost of product wont very in my case, in that case i am maintaining as  new product, formula should check for same name in purchase and sales. something like sumproduct.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works, Thanks for understanding my problem it was hard to explain